# How do I set the custom Gutenberg font size?

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

Mythemename.gutenberg.yml allows setting custom font size, but it doesn't work on Drupal 9. (It works on my old Drupal 8 site.)

Basing on [Creating custom font size presets in a Theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/gutenberg/creating-custom-font-size-presets-in-a-theme), custom font sizes could be added in the .gutenberg.yml file for the theme.

The colors appear on the Gutenberg with the following settings, but the "Mega" font size doesn't.

#### Mythemename.gutenberg.yml

```yaml
theme-support:
  colors:
    - slug: "black"
      name: "Black"
      color: "#000000"
    - slug: "dark-grey"
      name: "Dark Grey"
      color: "#555555"
  fontSizes:
    - slug: "mega"
      name: "Mega"
      size: 72
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a settings.js in your theme your JS file should look like this:

   ```js
   (function (Drupal) {

     var settings = {};

     window.DrupalGutenberg = window.DrupalGutenberg || {};
     window.DrupalGutenberg.defaultSettings = settings;

   })(Drupal);
   ```
2. Add it your themename.libraries.yml
3. In your themename.gutenberg.yml attach the library you created ex. `libraries-edit: themename/gutenberg`

After that clear cache and you'll able to see your custom fontsize preset.

[image]

Comment: `gutenburg` instead of `gutenberg`, really? Or is this a typo? 

Comment: yes its a typo in library.. the important is the themename.gutenberg.yml

Comment: @alvin For some reason, this only works if the Example Block enable.